# Vector of Structs is not sorting C++

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I need to sort a struct which consists of numbers and indexes so that I can check the index and the number after sorting.
MY struct is:

```
    struct data{
     float   number;
      size_t index;
      };

    //My sorting function is:
     bool by_number( const data& left, const data& right)
               {
               return (left.number < right.number);
    }

   // My code to sort is:
    std::vector<data>dist_sort;
    dist_sort.reserve(5);
    dist_sort[0].number=33;
    dist_sort[1].number=36;
    dist_sort[2].number=12;
    dist_sort[3].number=103;
    dist_sort[4].number=233;

    dist_sort[0].index=1;
    dist_sort[1].index=2;
    dist_sort[2].index=3;
    dist_sort[3].index=4;
    dist_sort[4].index=5;

    std::sort(dist_sort.begin(),dist_sort.end(),by_number);

    cout<<dist_sort[0].number<<endl;
    cout<<dist_sort[0].index<<endl;
```

I would expect the output to be 12 and 3 but I am not getting it. The code compiles and I have included all the relevant headers. Please help me out! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
dist_sort.reserve(5);
```

will reserve enough space, but the elements are not actually constructed. This is wrong.

You need `resize` instead. Or just use `push_back`, instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: Thank you!!!! That worked. Though I am not very clear about the usage of reserve.

Comment: @user1705329 you can also create a vector with 5 `data` objects on one go without needing to resize or push_back, see my answer. Although the clearest way would be to push_back `data` objects with the right values, and not modify them via `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `std::vector` wrong. `reserve` only reserves memory for further inserts, it doesn't change the number of actual elements the vector contains (i.e. doesn't change what `size()` reports).

Thus, you're passing a vector of size 0 to `std::sort()`, and it consequently does nothing.

Either replace `reserve(5)` with `resize(5)`, or replace the element assignments with calls to `push_back()`.

The only reason to ever use `reserve()` is to avoid reallocations (and hence copying) when inserting a large number of elements. `std::vector` stores the elements in a continouos block of memory, and must therefore copy all elements if a newly inserted elements doesn't fit into the previously allocated block. `std::vector` usually doubles the allocated size of the memory region each time that happens, which drives the average cost of an insert down to O(n) (from O(n^2), which it would be if the copying happened upon *every* insert). But the costs of all that copying can still be significant, e.g. if you insert tousands (or more) elements into a previously empty `std::vector`. In that case, you'd make it allocated a memory block of the desired size in advance with `reserve()`, and the individual inserts then only have to store the element and increment the vector size. But `reserve()` never modifies observable state, only internal invisible state of the vector.